# IMPORTRANGE #VALUE! error in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, valueerror

I have 2 spreadsheets, and I want to pull the cells in the 1st one to the 2nd. I wrote a QUERY to filter columns and get the total profit values with SUM(), but when I imported the needed cells with calculated values into another spreadsheet using IMPORTRANGE, it gave a `#VALUE!` error. Are there any ways to import them, so that when the values change in the 1st spreadsheet, it will automatically change in the 2nd one as well?
Attached screenshots below, queries are written in the 'sum' cells

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you put the mouse over the error, what does it say?

Comment: nothing, there is no error explanation, just a plain `#VALUE!`

Comment: Try importing only U2 to see what happens

Comment: After a few times of refreshing the spreadsheet, the #VALUE! error disappeared. Now everything works fine, thank you!

Comment: Maybe you have too many rows in that source sheet? Probably it was just loading data. I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the first option you can use FILTER, and for the second SUBTOTAL. For the first something like: `=LAMBDA(q,SUM(FILTER (INDEX(q,,16),INDEX(q,,4)<>"Cancelled",Month(INDEX(q,,2))=2)))(IMPORTRANGE(...))` changing the value inside INDEX to the column you're applying the filters to. And with Subtotal try with `=SUBTOTAL(109,D:D)`

I suggest you upload more information for a more specific answer

Comment: Using SUBTOTAL helped, and I want to take this value into another spreadsheet using IMPORTRANGE again, but it returned only the total sum without applied filters. How can I import the SUBTOTAL value into another spreadsheet considering the applied filter view?

Comment: That possibly is an issue, since when you're importing data you're not applying filter views... try using the Sum and Filter option; or you could use SUMIFS without the filter views. Try them and re-upload the question with your current process

Comment: I used Query and Sum and it worked. Is there a way to pull data from another spreadsheet other than  IMPORTRANGE?